# How do you store objects in python and how you access them

Tags: list, object, python-3.x, nested-lists, dictionary

during our school project we have a task to implement a working "Login System" using python.
I have done almost everything but I keep struggling with two of the functions implemented in the program. I will try to explain as much as i can what is the purpose of the system so you will be able to understand what i am facing with :)
Basically I am using objects for 2 roles of users ( Admin and general user ), and a book objects. Each user can login to the system and them he is presented with 5 different choices: add book, remove book, list book, share books (this one checks if any other user is reading the same book), and exit. I am having extreme difficulties with removing a book and sharing a booklist.

So far I have been storing my objects inside a list and have managed to complete all the functions so they were working properly. but heres the problem: This is how i stored objects inside a nested list so each book can be associated with a desired user

```
books=[book1,[user1],book2,[user1,user3],book3,[user3,user2],book4,[user1,user4,user3]]
```

But whenever i try to delete a book i use this function and it wont work. I know this block of code is basically useless for you but I have posted it anyway so you can maybe get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

```
total=len(books)
a=input("\nType in the book you want to delete:\n")
if (total!=0):
    for i in range(total):
        if(a==books[i].title):
            del(books[i])
            print("Book has been deleted\n\n")
            print(books)
            break
```

The following block of code is used for a sharing book function and is actually working.

```
books2=[]          
books3=[]          
xStr=input("Enter the name of the book\n")
for i in range(len(books)):
    if (i%2==1):               #This will select only users asociated with a book
        books2.append(books[i])
    if (i%2==0):               #This will select only the books
        books3.append(books[i])
for i in range(len(books2)):        
    for j in range(len(books2[i])): 
        if (books3[i].title==xStr): 
                print("Book: ",books3[i],"is also used by:",books2[i][j-1].username)
```

I have also tried with dictionaries but it didn't work.

So what I would like to know is: 
- which in your opinion would be the best way to store objects for this kind of a program
- which data structure should I use and how it is done basically

I hope I didn't complicate too much and sorry for my bad english :)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list is not optimal, there are better ways to go about this.

Important thing to realize is that a single object can be referred to in several lists or dictionaries. Also, objects can contain list attributes.

So you can maintain a list of all books. And a list of all users.

And a user can have a book list attribute that can then refer to books too, for example the ones he has read:

```
class User:
    booksRead = []
```

or, using the constructor:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.booksRead = []
```

Then to add a book to a user's list:

```
user.booksRead.append(book)
```

This is just one of many ways to organize this. If you wish to look up items in a list based on a key, use a dictionary.

Comment: I see what you mean. Could you please show me with an example how i could link the 2 objects (User, Book) together if thats not too much trouble for you. And thank you for your response

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes much more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find better ways to organize your data as you learn more and write more code; for now, take a close look at the difference between your delete code and your sharing code . . . (hint: your sharing code knows that only every *other* entry is a book).

Comment: I know what is the difference between the two functions but I only posted them there so you could have more details about what I am trying to do here :) The main problem i'm having is storing the details not the functions itself